# How many bit string of length n has no consecutive ones except the last two bits

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, binary

I'm looking for the number of an n-bits long bit string having no consecutive ones except the last two bits. Let me clarify the question by making some examples. Let say $n=5$, then:

$$\text{String 1: } \color{red}{00011} \text{  Good}$$
$$\text{String 2: } \color{red}{01011} \text{  Good}$$
$$\text{String 3: } \color{red}{11011} \text{  No (two consecutive ones before the end)}$$
$$\text{String 4: } \color{red}{10111} \text{  No (two consecutive ones before the end)}$$
$$\text{String 5: } \color{red}{10010} \text{  No (one of the last two bits isn't 1)}$$

I'm looking for the number of "Good" strings. Although finding the number of strings with all zero except the last two bits is easy, I'm stuck with dealing with the case of alternating one's and zero's in the strings. I appreciate any help or tips :D.

Comment: I posted a hint/answer that involved Inclusion-Exclusion.  Subsequently Rezha Adrian Tanuharja suggested that a recursive relation is a better way of attacking the problem.  I am not familiar with that approach in this type of problem.  The math in my (now deleted) answer is so ugly that I deleted the answer, since there may be a significantly better approach.  If you can't solve the problem any other way, flag me with a @user2661923 comment and I will undelete my answer, for you to examine.

Comment: @user2661923 hi there, I posted an answer using recursive relation, however I am working so could not write step by step answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any such binary number is a $n-3$ digits binary numbers with no consecutive ones followed by $011$. Therefore you just need to find out how many $n-3$ digits binary numbers with no consecutive ones exist.

Any $m$ digits binary number with no consecutive ones is either a $m-1$ digits binary number with no consecutive ones followed by $0$ or a $m-2$ digits binary number with no consecutive ones followed by $01$. Therefore, if $k_{m}$ is the number of $m$ digits binary numbers with no consecutive ones, we have the following recursive relation

$$
k_{m}=k_{m-1}+k_{m-2}
$$

I suggest to read more about recursive relation and how to solve them. I cannot write the full answer because I am working :)

The solution is $k_{m}=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{m}+\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{m}$

Now the answer to your original question is $k_{n-3}$

Comment: @Meow I really like this approach.

Comment: $(k_m)$ is just the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) missing the first element.

Comment: Thanks. But wow,  I didn't think that the number of a bit string can actually relate to the golden ratio. What a mind blown.

Comment: @Meow the beauty of maths :)